# Importing node-modules with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to get this to work, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere on SO. When trying to compile this single-file app:

```
import http = require('http')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Using the command "tsc app.ts --module 'commonjs'" I get the following error (not using the --module flag gives me an additional error telling me that I need it to compile external modules):

```
error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module '"http"'.
error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

Comment: try `var` instead of `import`. `var http = require('http')`

Comment: gives me `error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'require'.`. All examples I've seen use the `import` declaration.

Comment: if you use var, your import won't be typed correctly.

Comment: @Shoerob Can you elaborate a bit more on your comment. Do you mean that if we use 'var' instead of 'import', intelliSense wouldn't work on it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

TypeScript needs to know that `http` is present.

## Updated

Install the type definitinos for node:

```
npm install @types/node
```

## Old answer

Follows these two steps

- Download the `node.d.ts` file from here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node
- At the top of your file add:

  ```
  /// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
  ```

PS: See a sample test file : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node-tests.ts

Comment: I'm scratching my head now, since I was sure I had tried adding the referencepath. I even had it in my folder. Anyway, it works now, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you didn't post code that included the reference. That would have become hard to track ;)

Comment: @basarat I copies the node.d.ts file you've pointed to, but its throwing plenty of "File not found errors" in the .d.ts file  - especially for files like "crypto" "net" and "stream". Can you point me to these files or a stable version of node.d.ts

Comment: @basarat I've asked a question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437808/how-can-you-enable-nodejs-and-expressjs-into-typescript

Comment: How would this work with a module already written in Typescript? Would it need a definition file? I've asked the question here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175152/do-modules-written-in-typescript-need-a-definition-file-for-import

Comment: Worked for me too, though it's unclear why I need to add some external files as hacks (node.d.ts) in order for TypeScript to work...

Comment: @centurion you cannot have type safety without telling the compiler about the types.

Comment: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/master/node/node.d.ts` Save yourself a second on github :)

Comment: @jocull why stop there. `tsd install node` ;)

Comment: Could you explain what node.d.ts does in your answer?

Comment: All links to Github are broken. Is this answer still valid?

Comment: @Naktibalda, take a look at the question [How to find module “fs” in MS Code with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260901/how-to-find-module-fs-in-ms-code-with-typescript) It's an more recent solution

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had `noResolve` set to `true` in my tsconfig.json file. This was causing errors with the references to the .d.ts files that I had included at the top of my TypeScript files.

Answer (score -3):

Shouldn't it be something like

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
import http = module('http')
```

I mean, shouldn't you use `module` instead of `require` ?

Comment: `module` was deprecated in favor or `require` to be more consistent with the generated js

Comment: How would this work with a module already written in Typescript? Would it need a definition file? I've asked the question here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175152/do-modules-written-in-typescript-need-a-definition-file-for-import

Comment: @basarat aren't 'module' and 'require' separate in typescript's context. I was of the opinion that 'module' is for internal modules and 'require' is for external modules.

Comment: no. `module` has been deprecated for a long time. Its `import/require`