# How can you enable NodeJS and ExpressJs into Typescript

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, webstorm

I'm hoping to find a .d.ts file for both Node and Express, which would enable Intellisense, in typescript. So far, I've tried using a Node.d.ts file provided here:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node

But enabliing this file throws a lot of "file not found" errors in Webstorm, for files like "crypto" "net" and "stream" I'm not sure where to find these. They don't seem to be available on Github.

--EDIT--

Errors have somehow changed on their own and now I'm seeing errors for functions "write" and "listen". So farmy program runs, but its troublesome to have the errors.

I'm coding in webstorm.

Comment: do you mean 'incompatible override' errors shown for some functions declared in node.d.ts?

Comment: Could you provide the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @lena Interestingly, the errors have changed now, since I made some modifications to the files. Now it says - "Incompatible override for member from Server/Writable Stream".

Comment: I've posted a fresh question and its better framed over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515705/definitely-typed-nodejs-express-definition-file-has-errors

Comment: @EternallyCurious since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515705/definitely-typed-nodejs-express-definition-file-has-errors is answered and so is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542254/typescript-cant-find-modules can this question be deleted?

Comment: @basarat. Yes it can be. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the TEAN project, combining Typescript+ExpressJS+Angular+NodeJS

https://github.com/urigoren/TEAN/