# "Definitely typed" NodeJS + Express definition file has errors

Tags: node.js, express, definitelytyped

I am trying to convert my project that has NodeJS + ExpressJS to Typescript.

I got the definition files from Definitely Typed, but they seem to have plenty of errors:

```
export interface ClientRequest extends events.NodeEventEmitter, stream.WritableStream    
{
    // Extended base methods
    write(str: string, encoding?: string, fd?: string): boolean;
    write(buffer: NodeBuffer): boolean;

    write(chunk: any, encoding?: string): void;
    end(data?: any, encoding?: string): void;
    abort(): void;
    setTimeout(timeout: number, callback?: Function): void;
    setNoDelay(noDelay?: Function): void;
    setSocketKeepAlive(enable?: boolean, initialDelay?: number): void;
}

export interface Server extends net.Server {
    // Extended base methods
    listen(port: number, host?: string, backlog?: number, listeningListener?: Function): void;
    listen(path: string, listeningListener?: Function): void;
    listen(handle: any, listeningListener?: Function): void;

    listen(port: number, host?: string, callback?: Function): void;
    close(): void;
    address(): { port: number; family: string; address: string; };
    addContext(hostName: string, credentials: {
        key: string;
        cert: string;
        ca: string;
    }): void;
    maxConnections: number;
    connections: number;
}
```

The methods "write" and listen throw the error: "Incompatible override for member of writable stream".

In the app.js file the `var app = express();` function throws an error: Method expression is not a function type:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var expose = require("express-expose");
var fs = require("fs");
var formidable = require("formidable");
var upload = require('Upload');

var app = express();
var HOST = "localhost";
var PORT = 8080;
```

Comment: Probably the definitions are outdated. Fix the error and make a pull request to the Definitly typed project. This is how open source works ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'incompatible override' - it's a bug in webStorm, please vote for [WEB-10239](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10239)

'Method expression is not a function type:' can't reproduce in WebStorm 7.0.2

Comment: What do you mean by "can't reproduce in Webstorm 7.0.2". That's the version of webstorm I currently have. And as far as the bug is concerned, can we jsut ignore the warnings and proceed? And expect it to work normally?

Comment: One more thing! your answers have been very helpful. I've also asked  question on Quora regarding how to create Typescript definition files in general. Can you please try to answer that? Here's the link: http://www.quora.com/TypeScript/Is-there-a-tool-or-procedure-to-convert-Javascript-files-to-Typescript

Comment: There are no tools (at least I'm not aware of any) to create typescript files out of javascript... Typescript compiler can generate ambient declarations (d.ts) files out of .ts files (see --declaration option), can can't do this for javascript. Of course, as a dirty hack, you can try renaming your .js files to .ts and then run the typescript compiler for them with -declaration option, but this will likely fail, as the compiler won't understand most of js constructions and extract declarations from them

Comment: See also http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/how-to-create-a-ambient-class-declarations-in-typescript-tutorial/ - a tutorial on creating d.ts fil;es from javascript libraries. Note also that you can find d.ts files for most popular libraries at https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Thanks. Thats helpful. I've gotten a few files from Definitely Typed - especially for NodeJS and Expres, which has led to some errors. I've asked a question concerning that, which, maybe, you could answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542254/typescript-cant-find-modules - Thanks again.

Comment: And can you please explain what do you mean by "can't reproduce in Webstorm 7.0.2"

Comment: exactly what is written - I can'see any errors reported for 'var app = express(); ' in code similar to yours. There are might be some other parts of your code/libraries that affect this behavior

Comment: Thank you! Can you please help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542254/typescript-cant-find-modules