# Typescript can't find modules

Tags: express, typescript

I have an exported module in one file(upload.ts) in Typescript that I'm not able to import into another file(application.ts) without an error. Also, I'm not able to import ExpressJS.

Here's Upload.ts

```
/// <reference path="Main.d.ts" />

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');

export class Upload{

    public parse(req, res, next) {
       ...
    }

    public save(req, res, next) {
       ...
    }

    public respond(req, res, next) {
       ...
    }

    public errors(err, req, res, next) {
       ...
    }
};
```

Here's application.ts

```
/// <reference path="Main.d.ts" />

var http = require("http");
import express = require("express");
import upload = require("Upload");
var upload = new upload.Upload();

var app = express.express();
var HOST = "localhost";
var PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.logger());
app.use(app.router);
```

The `var app = express.express();` code throws an error: Unresolved function or method express. I've imported express.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/express

Here's the error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'upload'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\untitled\server\main.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Here's the header file, that references to both:

```
/// <reference path="upload.ts" />
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="application.ts" />
/// <reference path="express.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to:

- make sure to put both `express.d.ts` and `node.d.ts` into your project directory, near your application files
- import them into your application

Example:

```
/// <reference path="libs/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="libs/node.d.ts" />

import http = require("http");
import express = require("express");
import upload = require("Upload");

var upload = new upload.Upload();
var app = express();
```

`Upload` module can be referenced in similar way.
BTW, your code looks more like javascript then typescript

Comment: Actually I have already done that. There is a common header file that all files refer to and that refers back to all files. I'm in the process of transitioning from Javascript to Typescript