# WebStorm TypeScript Support with node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am trying to create a simple TypeScript project in WebStorm that imports a Node.js module. I have downloaded the relevant library TypeScript definition in settings and have specified `--module commonjs` in compiler settings, but I am receiving a `Cannot find external module` error when I try to actually import the module.

This is the most basic example I can think of. What am I missing here?

[image: Source Code + Project Layout]
[image: Library Settings]
[image: TypeScript Compiler Settings]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing node-modules with TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378503/importing-node-modules-with-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need at the very top of your file:

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
```

I'm not yet sure how to reference the Definitely Type node definitions you've downloaded inside the Webstorm IDE.

Try manually download node.d.ts from:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

and drop it into your working directory.

Comment: Definition files downloaded via JavaScript - Libraries are External libraries used by WebStorm to enhance code completion (more on that (more on that [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/)).
If you want to use then for compilation, you need to download that from GitHub and add to your project files.

Comment: Sorry, let this one slip by. I did try manually adding the files, and it didn't seem to work unless it was in the same directory. It's quite possible I did it incorrectly at the time. That said, I think we determined there are two bugs in WebStorm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16512.

Comment: @mdierker According to your report, it is still not fixed. Absolute path and symlink would not help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tsconfig.json then you can tell WebStorm to use it. Search for it under Languanges & Frameworks > TypeScript