# how to use npm libraries with typescript and ES6?

Tags: npm, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to target ES6 as output. This is for a node server side app that I can run on the bleeding-edge iojs distro, which hopefully supports the latest es6 syntax.

But I'm not clear how to use standard NPM libraries with the new import syntax?

`require` is now a bad word. I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263434/1146785) but

```
import http from "http";
import request from "request";
```

gives

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'
```

Is there a way to use these standard node libs, or other NPM modules already, without a complex transpile/babel build chain?

Comment: How are you executing ES6 modules with node?

Comment: how should I be? I want to use standard library node modules as above, http etc. but am stuck at that, the first step. including other custom libraries will be the next problem...

Comment: Is your code running client-side / server-side / both ? If client-side, how do you run it (webpack/browserify ?).

Comment: The issue is probably this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18378503/218196 .

Comment: @FelixKling that looks like an answer if you'd like the karmapoints :)

Comment: If it solves your problem this question should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http'

You need to include `node.d.ts` in your compilation context.

Also `import http from "http";` is wrong. Should be `import * as http from "http";` or `import http = require("http");`

Comment: Please just vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: @Bergi that comment is why stack overflow can suck sometimes.