# How to use node assert module with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't get typescript to compile this one-line file:

```
import assert = require("assert");
```

Here's the command i tried:

```
$ tsc --module commonjs --moduleResolution node index.ts
```

How can i import the `assert` or `http` or anything that ships with node?

**Edit: Error Message**

```
index.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'assert'.
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378503/importing-node-modules-with-typescript/18380150#18380150