# How to find module "fs" in VS Code with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I'm running on a MacBook Air.  I installed VS Code as an IDE and also have TypeScript installed.

I have a simple file with just this line:

```
import fs = require('fs');
```

I'm getting a red squiggly under the 'fs' inside the parenthesis and the error message is `[ts] Cannot find module 'fs'.` The file has a .ts extension. I'm new to JavaScript and to TypeScript, but I was under the impression that `fs` was a core module, so how could it not be found?  How do I fix the problem?

Other things that I tried already:

- Putting a simple function body in the file and then compiling on the command line with `tsc`.  I get an essentially equivalent error there: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.`
- On the command line `sudo npm install fs -g`.  This reports apparent success, but doesn't fix the problem.

I poked around SE and the web, but the answers that seemed close all appear to assume that 'fs' is available.

Comment: You're definitely executing this code with `node`?

Comment: The plan is to execute it with node, yes.  Local file access is ok for the current application. @peteb

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You need to include the definition file for node.

**TypeScript 2.0+**

Install using npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

**TypeScript < 2.0**

If you use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) then you can run this command:

```
typings install dt~node --global --save
```

Or if you are using typings < 1.0 run:

```
typings install node --ambient --save
```

Or if all else fails, manually download the file [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts) and include it in your project.

Comment: I used the command that you had prior to your edit, and that did the trick. (`typings install node --ambient --save`)  Thanks!

Comment: @Brick yes that will work. The command in the answer is for typings 1.0 which was just released

Comment: This is out of date, these days types should usually be installed with npm, as in [Abe's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413226/874671).

Comment: With yarn: `yarn add @types/node --dev`

Comment: After installing `@types/node`, you may need to restart Code to get it to recognize the modules properly. This should only be the case with native node modules, and may not even be an issue for you depending on your build of Code.

Comment: Tried it. But still didn't work for me. Any other reason for still getting `Error: Can't resolve 'fs'` ?

Comment: @barath did you find a solution?  I also have this error.

Comment: For someone who already has @types/node installed but still gets this error, you need to add "node" into the "types" field of tsconfig.json. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413226/10706866 to get the gist of the syntax

Answer (score 64):

There is a better way now without going to the previous tsd or typings tools.
NPM now has the @types package for typescript. In this example you need the package `@types/node`:

```
npm install "@types/node" --save-dev
```

Make sure you are using the save-dev option to only install the types in development mode, not in production. You should have the latest node libraries when use the npm install "@types/" syntax...

It not finding the fs package because the previous tools typings most likely not using the latest node.d.ts definition file.

Your tsconfig.json file needs to be updated to find these type packages.
My example if using jquery, jqueryui and node types. Assuming you need the syntax to work for your code editor as well, in this case the 'atom' code editor

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
        "jquery",
        "jqueryui",
        "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build"
],
"filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
],
"atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
}
}
```

Answer (score 43):

"fs" is a core Node module and I think your import statement syntax is a little off. Try:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

Comment: Ah the typings for Node isn't included. Try adding this file and a reference path to it: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

Comment: @EricN The page leads to a 404. Typings are needed even if the module is part of the whole NodeJs core ?

Comment: Yeah the typing is necessary. Node isn't written in Typescript so it doesn't have any of the type data that Typescript looks for. The definition file provides all that type data for you.

Answer (score 29):

All you need is "moduleResolution" set to "node" in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      ...
      "moduleResolution": "node"
      ...
  }
}
```

execute

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

and now you can use standard TypeScript import:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

Comment: Tried but still getting same problem

Comment: @pardeepjain, any chance you have old typescript? Using vscode? Check Typescript version on the status bar.

Comment: I only needed the first part of this - I have a tiny script which _doesn't need_ a packages.json file

Answer (score 16):

You have three options in `tsconfig.json` (here: Node 11+), see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types):

Either **specifiy** both `typeRoots` and `types`, only `typeRoots` or **remove** both lines completely (recommended):

```
{"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],  // "typeRoots": [] -> won't work
  "types": ["node"]                      // "types": [] -> won't work
}}
```

Install types:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Use promise based file system (e.g to use async / await):

```
import {promises as fs} from 'fs';

async function foo() {
    ...
    await fs.writeFile('./yourPath', 'YourContent');
}
```

Comment: When I created a declarations folder to put my `.d.ts` files in and created a `typeRoots` array in my `compilerOptions` I had not specified the `node_modules/@types` and that's what caused the error for me. Once I added that to the `typeRoots` array, it worked again.

Comment: Excellent answer. Unlike 90% of folks here, I already had `node` types installed but was running into the issue where core `node` modules (like `os` where not being found at *runtime*)

Comment: Thanks. I was missing `types:["node"]` in my tsconfig:compilerOptions.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript knows about modules based upon conventions , check [Module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) for more detail.

Also for IDE to know about `fs` module, you have to provide typings for node.

Also check this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5812)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by updating npm version and npm install "@types/node" --save-dev

Comment: This is the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Check your `tsconfig.json` to see if you have a bad [`include` setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include).

I ran into this issue because my `tsconfig.json` file specified an `include` list that did **not** include the file I had the error in. In other words, the file wasn't being properly processed by TypeScript.

In my case, my `include` was set to `["src"]`, but my file was inside a subdirectory called `scripts`. After adjusting `include` to `["scripts", "src"]`, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the `@types/node` package and still **having the TS error**, try the following:

1. add `"node"` to `"compileOptions"` `"types"` in `tsconfig.json`

e.g.

```
"compileOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
}
```

2. also, add `"node"` to `"compilerOptions"` `"types"` in `tsconfig.app.json`
3. save all and ***restart TS server***, by doing the following:

- **Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- **Win**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on my side this work

```
 const fs = require('fs') as typeof import('fs');
```

of for nwjs with vitejs

```
 const fs = nw.require('fs') as typeof import('fs');
```

this remove the `any`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this kind of error **if your file (script) is inside a directory that starts with `.`** : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13399

I had the same exact problem (`Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.`) although `@types/node` was installed.
My script was in `.husky` directory and adding:

```json
    "include": [
        "./**/*",
        "./.husky/**/*",
    ],
```

to the `tsconfig.json` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the contents of tsconfig.json for the "types": ["node"] setting, you might also want to take a look for the same content in tsconfig.app.json (if you have one).

Comment: Hey @wmm2! Glad you could join the community!  When putting code in your answer, you can make it a lot more readable as such by selecting the text, and pressing `Ctrl` + `K`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "esModuleInterop": true in your tsconfig.json and see if it fixes

Answer (score 0):

I tried the top options and got no difference, but once I moved the file to the src/ folder, or the folder specified as root in the tsconfig.json, then it was able to resolve the fs module.