# import stripe using node js + typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I need to import stripe in to my application

First i installed stripe npm package

```
npm install stripe --save
```

Stripe documentation says that secret key should be set before connect the api.

In Node it likes this

```
var stripe = require('stripe')(' your stripe API key ');
```

I need to convert it to typescript

I tried following way . but it didnt work for me

```
import * as stripe from 'stripe';
stripe('sk_test_...')
```

if some can help me to solve this problem it will great help to me to continue my project without delay.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378503/importing-node-modules-with-typescript?rq=1 ?

Comment: In 2023, Firebase has support for `.env`, `.env.dev`, `.env.prod`, ... files. [Read the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#env-variables)

Answer (score 66):

You can refer to the repo on GitHub:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...', {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
});

const createCustomer = async () => {
  const params: Stripe.CustomerCreateParams = {
    description: 'test customer',
  };

  const customer: Stripe.Customer = await stripe.customers.create(params);

  console.log(customer.id);
};
createCustomer();
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Note: the API version needs to be updated to "2020-08-27". Submitted an edit.

Comment: Now the API version is updated to "2022-08-01"

Comment: It's now "2022-11-15". Typescript will steer you to the right value.

Answer (score 33):

As of stripe 8.0.1 the package has its own typeing so it is not necessary to install additional types. Just import it like this:

> import Stripe from 'stripe';

Answer (score 29):

**Update:** The solution below is outdated and for those using `stripe@8.0.1` or greater the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700410/5024353) from [David Dehghan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705945/david-dehghan) should be used.

As [britzkopf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381230/5024353) said, stripe don't provide their own definitions yet (and probably never will), but you can use the type definitions from [@types/stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe).

```
npm install stripe @types/stripe
```

And then import and construct the `Stripe` class as follows.

```
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('xxx_xxx_xxx');
```

If you want finer grained imports for some reason you can use this (somewhat hacky) approach instead.

```
import { resources } from 'stripe';
const stripeData = require('stripe')('xxx_xxx_xxx');
const customers = new resources.Customers(stripeData, null);
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and the solution provided did not work for me:

```
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('xxx_xxx_xxx');
```

Using this approach, I got this error

> [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or
>   construct signature. stripe.ts(1, 1): Type originates at this import.
>   A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will
>   cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import
>   require here instead. (alias) class Stripe (alias) namespace Stripe
>   import Stripe

I got it working using `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `tsconfig.json`
With this compile option, the following is valid in TypeScript:

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const secret = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET!;
export const stripe = new Stripe(secret);
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true"` was the default in my case so I did not need to change anything.

Answer (score 8):

It's a [feature request](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/296). Go give it another thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage):

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_...');
```