# Typescript commonjs inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript

Was playing around with Ts and got stuck at this

```
"use strict";

declare const require: any;

const EventEmitter : any = require('events').EventEmitter;

class Foo extends EventEmitter{ //*error* Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I also tried to assign `EventEmitter` to an interface type of mine, which gave the same error.

How can I extend a class, with commonjs modules using Typescript?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
"use strict";

import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

class Foo extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

You may need to install type definition for 'events' module:

`npm install --save @types/node`

---

Update

You can still do the same with `require`:

```
"use strict";

import events = require('events');
const EventEmitter = events.EventEmitter;

class Foo extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

---

You should avoid using `: any` in general so you can use features like IntelliSense and compile-time type checking

Comment: Great answer. Maybe add a note on why using any is wrong in this case and bad in general?

Comment: thanks a lot! 
I really like the approach, but just for completion, would the `require` solution also be possible using something like `node.d.ts` , like mentioned here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378503/importing-node-modules-with-typescript

Comment: @xhallix Yes, you can. I've just updated the answer for that.